# Vale a pena estudar versões anteriores a 6 do Angular?

Tags: angular

Tentei pesquisar na internet e no próprio fórum, porém não encontrei algo muito claro e direto para minha pergunta então achei bom perguntar por aqui pois pode ser a dúvida de alguns.

Recentemente comecei a me aprofundar em web e, dentre os milhares de frameworks e bibliotecas, acabei optando por Angular. Recentemente ele teve uma build nova (versão 6) porém não há ainda muito conteúdo relacionado, no máximo existem cursos que ensinam angular 2, 4 ou 5 e no apêndice do curso eles mostram as mudanças para o Angular 6. Minha dúvida é simples: Posso me aprofundar em versões anteriores e depois aprender as novidades do 6 ou vale mais a pena esperar algo relacionado exclusivamente a ele ?

UPDATE:
Futuramente quero me aprofundar no esquema MEAN, então comecei pelo Front, depois passarei a estudar Node/Express e um banco não relacional Mongo. Também me chamou a atenção o framework Ionic para aplicações híbridas e vi que é possível integrá-lo ao meu projeto Angular-Cli (porém só a partir do Angular 2 por usar TypeScript, o que me faz não querer me aprofundar no 1).

Comment: Acho que isso é subjetivo e depende exclusivamente das suas necessidades; mas se o Angular 6 atende todas elas, não vejo motivos de estudar versões anteriores.

Comment: Recomendo: [Construindo Aplicações Web Com o Novo Angular (4, 5 e 6)](https://www.udemy.com/angular-pt/learn/v4/overview)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss adicionei meus planos futuros, realmente estava faltando isso para uma visão mais clara do problema.

Comment: Mas isso não muda o contexto. As necessidades que cito são técnicas: quais os tipos de projeto que desenvolverá, que problemas buscará resolver, quais as especificações do ambiente que servirá a aplicação, etc. Tem problemas que será mais fácil utilizar a versão X do que Y, cabe você, como desenvolvedor, analisar e decidir. Não existe uma resposta concreta para a sua pergunta, por isso foi fechada.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Eu irei partir para a última versão no fim das contas, a dúvida principal era se, eu aprendendo através de versões anteriores eu acabaria tendo que reinventar a roda inteira para absorver as novidades. Então nesse caso valeria a pena esperar algo relacionado apenas à versão 6.

Comment: A maioria das mudanças são em performance e arquitetura. O conhecimento necessário e aforma de fazer as coisas ainda e a mesma. A maioria das mudanças são incrementais.